# MediaRecorder: How to stop Video recording and play back in same video element?

Tags: mediarecorder

I am using a  with mediaRecorder

```
        function getUserMediaSuccess(stream) {
            $videoElement[0].srcObject = stream;
            $videoElement[0].autoplay = true;
            $videoElement[0].muted = true;
            $videoElement[0].controls = false;
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream, settings.recorderOptions);
        }
```

Once recording is finished, I want to play the recorded chunks.

I tried with:

```
        const blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : settings.recorderOptions.mimeType});
        $videoElement[0].src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

and also with

```
$videoElement[0].pause();
$videoElement[0].removeAttribute('src');
$videoElement[0].load();
$videoElement[0].src = settings.filename;
$videoElement[0].controls = true;
```

I cannot stop the video element of showing the real time webcam.

**I can play back the recorded video in ANOTHER video element**. But I want to use the SAME  that is used to display the webcam.

I also tried:

```
            localStream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
                track.stop();
            });
```

Which gives a black screen, but I am unable then to play back again the recorded video.

Comment: please try and provide a example as jsfiddle or here as embedded example - so its easier to reproduce your behavior.have you tried with the example at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder#example

Comment: Set the `srcObject` to `null` after the recording has been stopped: `$videoElement[0].srcObject = null;`

Answer (score 1):

it think you have done most things correctly.

based on the [mozilla MediaRecorder example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder#example) and some more research i think the *magic* is to *switch* between using `srcObject` and `src`:

- `srcObject` for mediaStream (getUserMedia live preview)
- `src` with `window.URL.createObjectURL`

this snippet works (if run un localhost or over https -
(maybe that the embedding does not fullfill all security things to allow access to getUserMedia..)

```js
const videoEl = document.getElementById('theVideoElement');
let mediaRecorder = null;
let mediaChunks = [];

function recordStart() {
    console.log('recordStart..');
    if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia (
            {
                audio: true,
                video: true,
            }
        )
        .then( stream => {
            videoEl.srcObject = stream;
            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

            mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
                mediaChunks.push(event.data);
            });

            mediaRecorder.addEventListener('stop', event => {
                console.log("recorder stopped");
                const blob = new Blob(mediaChunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm' });
                mediaBlobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                mediaChunks = [];
                videoEl.src = mediaBlobURL;
            });

            mediaRecorder.start();
            console.log("recorder started", mediaRecorder.state);

            window.setTimeout(event => {
                console.log("time is over.");
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
                console.log("recorder stopped");
                // stop getUserMedia stream - this way the cam and mic gets released.
                for (const track of stream.getTracks()) {
                    track.stop();
                }
                videoEl.srcObject = null;
                console.log("stream stopped.");
            }, 3000);
        })
        .catch( err => {
            console.error(`The following getUserMedia error occurred:\n ${err}`);
        });
    } else {
        console.error('getUserMedia not supported on your browser!');
    }
}


console.info('******************************************');
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    console.info('All resources finished loading.');
    const buttonEl = document.getElementById('button_start');
     buttonEl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        console.info('click!');
        recordStart();
    });
});
```

```css
button {
  display: block;
}

video {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<button id="button_start"> 
  start 
</button>

<video
    id="theVideoElement"
    autoplay
    controls
>
</video>
```

Comment: This code works but I get no audio on recorded video.